# Ruby error - '+': no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String (TypeError)

Tags: ruby, error-handling, encryption

This line is throwing the error:

```
charLine.each_index { |i| charLine[i] = (charLine[i] + shift)}
```

edit: `charLine[i]` is a number (ascii code) and `shift` is a number also

I know it has to do with trying to add the number in the variable shift to the byte ascii code I have in the charLine array index. But I'm not even dealing with strings at all which is why I'm so confused with this error... Here's the method with the error:

```
      def caesarCipher(string)
    puts "Original:\n #{string}"
    charLine = string.chars
    charLine.each_index { |i| charLine[i]=charLine[i].bytes }
    charLine.flatten!
    puts charLine.inspect

    shift = 1
    alphabet = ('A'..'Z').to_a
    while shift <= alphabet.size
      #moving up in the alphabet using ascii code
      charLine.each_index { |i| charLine[i] = (charLine[i] + shift)}
      #converting back to letters
      charLine.each_index { |x| charLine[x] = charLine[x].chr }

      puts "Shifted:\n #{charLine.inspect}"
      puts "With a letter shift of #{shift}"
      shift = shift + 1
      @@shiftyArray.push(charLine.flatten)
    end

  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to reproduce the problem and with some debugging output I can see that the first iteration runs fine and the problem only appears on the second iteration (shift = 2).

In the first iteration **charLine** is an *array of integers*, so integer + integer works out fine for this line: `charLine.each_index { |i| charLine[i] = (charLine[i] + shift)}`

But then charLine is converted into an *array of strings* on the next line of the loop:

```
 #converting back to letters
 charLine.each_index { |x| charLine[x] = charLine[x].chr }
```

So at the start of second iteration charLine is now an array of Strings, because it wasn't converted back. Then on the .each_line it tries to add up string + integer and it blows up.

The solution is to re-map your string array to integer at the start of every iteration.

```
charLine.map!(&:ord)
```

The alternative is to not modify the array and save the results into a temp variable, here is a working example:

```
def caesar_cipher(string)
   shiftyArray = []
   charLine = string.split(//)
   charLine.map!(&:ord)

   shift = 1
   alphabet_size = 26
   while shift <= alphabet_size
     shifted_array = charLine.map { |c| (c + shift) < 122 ? (c + shift) : (c + shift) - 26 }
     shifted_array.map!(&:chr)
     p shifted_array

     shift += 1
     shiftyArray.push(shifted_array.join)
   end
 end

 caesar_cipher("testing")
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks, completely solved everything :) I need to study the map method a little more

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add `shift`, which is a Fixnum to a String.  Just call `to_s` on shift to convert it to a string:

```
charLine.each_index { |i| charLine[i] = (charLine[i] + shift.to_s)}
```

Comment: Won't work in these circumstances, I need shift to be an integer to change the ascii code in charLine[i]

Comment: it gives this error instead with 'shift.to_s'
"'+': String can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)"